# Javascript, return to previous tab on reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with tabs based on the example shown at w3schools.com.  Leveraging their examples I've tweaked up the html and css to my liking but I'm running into an issue with page reloads.  I want to return to the last selected tab (i.e. active tab) when the page reloads whether by hitting the reload button or a submit button to send data to a database.

The javascript posted below first hides the tab page content, then clears all active tabs, then sets whatever tab is clicked on, to the active tab, while clearing the previous active tab.

I've played with the tab clearing code in the the java script and keep running into the problem of not clearing the active tab when I click a different tab, and/or clearing everything when I hit reload.

So I started doing some research and ran across the option to use sessionstore() on the MDN as a possibility.  The basic examples MDN gives make complete sense, but applying them to this tab design is not intuitive to me.  I start a session when the users logs in so there is a session in place to leverage from.

I've seen a few other questions on this site related to this but I'm not able to translate those to this.

Don't know if i'm barking up the wrong tree on this, but one way or another I'd like to store the current tab in the current session so that the user is returned to that tab if they do a page reload or hit a submit button to send/get data to the database.

Code I'm fiddling with is below:

```js
function openEDO(event, plannerName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(plannerName).style.display = "block";
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click()
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    border: 0px solid #003399;
    width: 1200px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #003399;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 15px;
    float:left
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #003399;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #003399;
    color: #ffcc00;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
    width: 1190px;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PI')">Personal Info</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PH')">Professional History</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'P1')">Plan 1</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="PI" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="PH" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="P1" class="tabcontent">
</div>
```

With this code the page always returns to the home page on page load.  Obviously I can remove that and have no tab be the "default" page, or make some other page the default on page reload.  But what I want is the ability to go back to last tab in the current session.  I also want to still retain the current function of starting at the home page when a user first logs in and starts a new session.

If any one could help me sort this out I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage`, add id to each button, on page load check if sessionStorage already set? If yes, click the active button. Otherwise, click the default home button:

In your function `openEDO` set sessionStorage first using:

`sessionStorage.setItem('sel_tab', plannerName);`

#### https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/2a6nsvp8/

JS:

```
  var seltab = sessionStorage.getItem('sel_tab');
  if (seltab) {
    document.getElementById("Btn" + seltab).click();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("BtnHome").click();
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <button class="tablinks" id="BtnHome" onclick="openEDO(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" id="BtnPI" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PI')">Personal Info</button>
  <button class="tablinks" id="BtnPH" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PH')">Professional History</button>
  <button class="tablinks" id="BtnP1" onclick="openEDO(event, 'P1')">Plan 1</button>
```

> ## Window.sessionStorage
>
> REF:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
>
> [image]

Comment: Fantastic, got this working right away and when I log out and log back in, it starts off at the home page as desired (as if - else statements should).  My only problem now is that my window.open script i've got running in my submit php isn't working....probably just a little adjustment....we'll see.

Comment: When I started testing this, it broke a bunch of other stuff (particularly my sessions which links everything else to the users login credentials, logout which is supposed to destroy the session in php and I added session clear in javascript but hasn't worked yet...and a few others).  I'll keep working on this and see what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You would you localstorage or sessionstorage for that.  Set the value of the tab index as the users uses your app.  On page load, you can read the value of localstorage or session storage and use basic javaScript to focus on whatever tab you want.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Each of the posted answers are spot on and each of you gave similar answers.  Appreciate your time reviewing this and giving feedback that set me on the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to remember active tab. I have modified the JavaScript code to do so, but unfortunately StackOverflow's snippet iframe won't allow you access to storage, so you'll have to test it out on a different environment.

```js
function openEDO(event, plannerName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(plannerName).style.display = "block";
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
    
    // remember current tab
    localStorage.setItem('activeTabId', plannerName);
}

// restore current tab
var activeTabId = localStorage.getItem('activeTabId');
if (activeTabId) {
  document.getElementById(activeTabId).click();
} else {
  document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click()
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    border: 0px solid #003399;
    width: 1200px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #003399;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 15px;
    float:left
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #003399;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #003399;
    color: #ffcc00;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
    width: 1190px;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PI')">Personal Info</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'PH')">Professional History</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEDO(event, 'P1')">Plan 1</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="PI" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="PH" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="P1" class="tabcontent">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I'll try this out.  I figured I'd have to set the tab information into the sessionstorage, but didn't know exactly how to get that information in.  Daniel H's solution below is working (but now my window.open item in my php isn't working).  I'll try your and his solutions going forward and see what works best, since they are both very similar.